# Constructor not found errors on compile

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors, gwt-compiler

I am having a weird problem that I cannot get to the bottom of. I have a class as follows:

```
public class I18nTextBox extends I18nAbstractTextBox<String> {
    public I18nTextBox() {
        this("", Consts.MAXL_BASIC);
    }
    public I18nTextBox(String keyTitle) {
        this(keyTitle, Consts.MAXL_BASIC);
    }

    public I18nTextBox(String keyTitle, int maxLength, String ... substitutions) {
        super(keyTitle, maxLength, substitutions);
    }
    // ...
}
```

With its superclass defined as follows:

```
public abstract class I18nAbstractTextBox<T> extends TextBox implements IRefreshableDisplay, IModelDataField<T> {
    // some properties ...

    public I18nAbstractTextBox() {
        this("", Consts.MAXL_BASIC);
    }

    public I18nAbstractTextBox(String keyTitle) {
        this(keyTitle, Consts.MAXL_BASIC);
    }

    public I18nAbstractTextBox(String keyTitle, int maxLength, String ... substitutions) {
        // do some logic
    }
    //...
}
```

Eclipse shows no compiler errors whatsoever, yet when I run GWT's debug mode, as soon as it tries to load the app I get a whole load of **The constructor I18nTextBox() is undefined** errors, every time I instantiate the first class (`I18nTextBox`).

It used to be the case that there was just one class, the `I18nTextBox`, but we took it, made it abstract and created `I18nTextBox` to extend it because we needed a special type of typing, so I know that the class works in its own right.

To summarise:

- Constructor is defined on subclass, and in superclass.
- Eclipse sees nothing wrong.
- When project is compiled by the GWT compiler, I get loads of "constructor not found" errors.

No-one at work seems to be able to see the problem, does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

### Update

So it has been pointed out that a 2 argument constructor is missing, but there are two things to say on this:

- the argument `String ... substitutions` is an optional argument, so should default to null if not specified.
- this worked before when there was only I18nTextBox and no abstract super class (we abstracted as explained above).

If I go on and specify another constructor, as follows:

```
public I18nTextBox(String keyTitle, int maxLength) {
    this(keyTitle, maxLength, "");
}
```

Then I fix the error in `I18nTextBox`, but get the same error for `I18nIntegerTextBox` which is defined in exactly the same way:

```
public class I18nIntegerTextBox extends I18nAbstractTextBox<Integer> {
    public I18nIntegerTextBox() {
        this("", Consts.MAXL_BASIC);
    }
    public I18nIntegerTextBox(String keyTitle) {
        this(keyTitle, Consts.MAXL_BASIC);
    }
    public I18nIntegerTextBox(String keyTitle, int maxLength) {
        this(keyTitle, maxLength, "");
    }
    public I18nIntegerTextBox(String keyTitle, int maxLength, String ... substitutions) {
        super(keyTitle, maxLength, substitutions);
    }
    // ...
}
```

So I just don't understand what is going wrong!

Comment: I'm just curious, did you try deleting the rest of the constructors leaving just the I18nTextBox() in there? Does it produce the same error?

Comment: These errors happen under "Finding entry point classes" in the GWT compiler process, after "validating units" has completed successfully.

Comment: @Lenymm I have to implement the constructors with arguments, because they are not inherited by the subclass. If I don't, Eclipse complains (making it a Java error explicitly).

Comment: Oh yeah, you're totally missing a constructor there as Prabhaker stated. I still don't get why Eclipse doesn't warn you about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so we discovered the problem. Essentially the `this()` call was confusing the GWT compiler. It wasn't a javac error, but I have a feeling that when GWT was translating the Java into Javascript it was getting confused as to which `this()` we were referring to (the superclass or the subclass). The error was a bit cryptic, so I am not entirely sure, but I changed the constructors to all call `super()` (with however many arguments is appropriate). The code now looks like this:

```
public class I18nTextBox extends I18nAbstractTextBox<String> {
    public I18nTextBox() {
        super();
    }
    public I18nTextBox(String keyTitle) {
        super(keyTitle);
    }
    public I18nTextBox(String keyTitle, int maxLength, String ... substitutions) {
        super(keyTitle, maxLength, substitutions);
    }
    //...
}
```

Which fixes the problem, bizarrely.